# Origin of Yor's formula

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, math-history

For any two semimartingales $X$ and $Y$ it is true that
$$ \mathscr{E}(X)\mathscr{E}(Y) = \mathscr{E}(X+Y+[X,Y]);\tag{1}\label{1}$$
see for example II.8.19 in *Jacod, Jean; Shiryaev, Albert N.*, Limit theorems for stochastic processes., Grundlehren der Mathematischen Wissenschaften. 288. Berlin: Springer. xx, 661 p. (2003). [ZBL1018.60002](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1018.60002).
Some authors call \eqref{1} the **Yor formula**. What is the original source of this formula and who has given it its name?

Answer (score 1):

I have found it: In
*Jacod* (1979) [**Calcul stochastique et problèmes de martingales**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BFb0064907), the formula is credited to Proposition 4 in  *Yor* (1976) [**Sur les intégrales stochastiques optionnelles et une suite remarquable de formules exponentielles**](http://www.numdam.org/item/SPS_1976__10__481_0/).